# Why does curl_easy_strerror() return the same text for all errors?

Tags: curl

Whatever error code given as argument it always returns the same text "Error", except for CURLE_OK, which returns "No error". 
Shouldn't it give a specific error text for each error?

(My LIBCURL_VERSION is 7.28.1).

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: This test code: 

CURLcode err;
for (err=0; err <= 100; err++) {
  printf("curlE %d='%s'\n", err, curl_easy_strerror(err));
}

will print the following:

curlE 0 = 'No error'
curlE 1 = 'Error'   
curlE 2 = 'Error'   
curlE 3 = 'Error'   
curlE 4 = 'Error'   
curlE 5 = 'Error'   
curlE 6 = 'Error'  
(...etc...)
curlE 100 = 'Error'

Comment: (can you put that into the question?)

Answer (score 0):

Because the libcurl you have was built with verbose strings disabled.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).